In "The Godfather," is the name of Signor Abbandando's store idiomatic Italian?
In the famous American movie The Godfather, Don Corleone at one point works at a family grocery store known as Abbandando Grosseria.
According to the online Treccani dictionary of the Academia della Crusca, grosserìa can only refer to either foolishness or coarseness, or to a large work of goldsmithing. On the other hand, the word grossista does seem to exist with a meaning similar to "wholesaler," so I could imagine that in some dialect of Italian or in some language spoken in Italy (like Sicilian, although I cannot find it in Sicilian language databases like this one), it could mean the business of a grossista.
Is "grosseria" actually a plausible name for a grocery store in standard Italian, Sicilian dialects of Italian, or Sicilian itself? Or is it just a mistaken coinage by non-Italian-speaking Americans?

It certainly isn't Standard Italian. And as an Italian, it only sounds as an Italianisation  “by ear”of “grocery”. Grossista is different: it's someone who buys in grosso (or, more modernly, all'ingrosso), i.e., “in great quantities”, i.e., wholesale.
